# POSIX compliant way to work with a list of filenames possibly with whitespace

Tags: shell-script, filenames, quoting, posix, whitespace

I have seen Bash scripting guides suggesting the use of array for working with filenames containing whitespace. [DashAsBinSh](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) however suggests that arrays are not portable so I am looking for a POSIX compliant way of working with lists of filenames that may contain whitespace.

I am looking to modify the below example script so that it would `echo`

```
foo/target/a.jar
foo/target/b.jar
bar/target/lol whitespace.jar
```

Here is the script

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

INPUT="foo/target/a.jar
foo/target/b.jar
bar/target/b.jar
bar/target/lol whitespace.jar"
# this would be produced by a 'ls' command
# We can execute the ls within the script, if it helps

dostuffwith() { echo $1; };

F_LOCATIONS=$INPUT
ALL_FILES=$(for f in $F_LOCATIONS; do echo `basename $f`; done)
ALL_FILES=$(echo "$ALL_FILES" | sort | uniq)

for f in $ALL_FILES
do
    fpath=$(echo "$F_LOCATIONS" | grep -m1 $f)
    dostuffwith $fpath
done
```

Comment: Possible same on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499486/how-to-mark-an-array-in-posix-sh

Answer (score 12, accepted):

POSIX shells have one array: the positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, etc., collectively refered to as `"$@"`).

```
set -- 'foo/target/a.jar' 'foo/target/b.jar' 'bar/target/b.jar' 'bar/target/lol whitespace.jar'
set -- "$@" '/another/one at the end.jar'
…
for jar do
  dostuffwith "$jar"
done
```

This is inconvenient because there's only one, and it destroys any other use of the positional parameters. Positional parameters are local to a function, which is sometimes a blessing and sometimes a curse.

If your file names are guaranteed not to contain newlines, you can use newlines as the separator. When you expand the variable, first turn off globbing with `set -f` and set the list of field splitting characters `IFS` to contain only a newline.

```
INPUT="foo/target/a.jar
foo/target/b.jar
bar/target/b.jar
bar/target/lol whitespace.jar"
…
set -f; IFS='
'                           # turn off variable value expansion except for splitting at newlines
for jar in $INPUT; do
  set +f; unset IFS
  dostuffwith "$jar"        # restore globbing and field splitting at all whitespace
done
set +f; unset IFS           # do it again in case $INPUT was empty
```

With items in your list separated by newlines, you can use many text processing commands usefully, in particular `sort`.

Remember to always put double quotes around variable substitutions, except when you explicitly want field splitting to happen (as well as globbing, unless you've turned that off).

Comment: Good answer and explanation. I'm going to mark this as accepted because this makes the original `sort | uniq` step work as intended.

Answer (score 5):

Since your `$INPUT` variable uses newlines as separators, I'm going to assume that your files will not have newlines in the names. As such, yes, there is a simple way of iterating over the files and preserving whitespace.

The idea is to use the `read` shell builtin. Normally `read` will split on any whitespace, and so spaces will break it. But you can set `IFS=$'\n'` and it will instead split on newlines only. So you can iterate over each line in your list.

Here's the smallest solution I could come up with:

```
INPUT="foo/target/a.jar
foo/target/b.jar
bar/target/b.jar
bar/target/lol whitespace.jar"

dostuffwith() {
    echo "$1"
}

echo "$INPUT" | awk -F/ '{if (!seen[$NF]++) print }' | \
while IFS=$'\n' read file; do
  dostuffwith "$file"
done
```

Basically it sends "$INPUT" to `awk` which deduplicates based on the file name (it splits on `/` and then prints the line if the last item hasn't been seen before). Then once awk has generated the list of file paths, we use `while read` to iterate through the list.

Comment: $ checkbashisms bar.sh 
possible bashism in bar.sh line 14 (<<< here string)

Comment: @EeroAaltonen Changed it to not use the herestring. Note though that with this change, the `while` loop, and thus `dostuffwith` is executed in a subshell. So any variables or changes made to the running shell will be lost when the loop completes. The only alternative is to use a full heredoc, which isn't that unpleasant, but I thought this would be preferable.

Comment: I'm awarding points based more on readability than smallness. This certainly works and already +1 for that.

Comment: `IFS="\n"` splits on backslash and n characters. But in `read file`, there's no splitting. `IFS="\n"` is still useful in that it removes the blank characters from $IFS which otherwise would have been stripped at the beginning and end of the input. To read a line, the canonical syntax is `IFS= read -r line`, though `IFS=anything read -r line` (provided _anything_ doesn't contain blanks) will work as well.

Comment: oops. Not sure how I managed that one. Fixed.